# Scipy installation issues from source?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to install scipy numpy from source for installing scikit learn from source. I managed to do it for numpy and scikit but for scipy I get an error,

> ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core

This is happening because numpy is not install in the site-packages directory for python, but in a custom directory. Any workaround this?

Comment: If that's the problem, then however you get Python to recognize that custom directory when it runs normally, you just need to do the same thing when running it on `setup.py`.

Comment: @abarnert I go into installation directory of numpy and import it, how can I do that while running install command

Comment: @abarnert I did what you suggested and that still does not work

Comment: It sounds like you _haven't_ installed numpy. You just have a `build_ext -i` type build. You need to actually _install_ it. Otherwise, how are you planning to use any of this? You can't be in the numpy directory and in the scipy directory and in the scikit directory all at the same time, and you can't use one without the others.

Comment: What exactly did you do with numpy (and why, if it's not obvious)?

Comment: I downloaded the tar ball and did python setup.py install --home="dir_name", same with scikits and was trying same for scipy... what is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of installing to a custom "home" is that you want to make that part of your `sys.path`. While you *can* do that by `cd`ing into that directory and starting Python (because `.` is part of the default `sys.path`), that's rarely a good idea. What you probably want to do is set a `PYTHONPATH` env variable, or extend your per-user site-packages, or something like that.

Or, even more simply, install into your system or user site-packages in the first place.

Or, if you don't want to pollute your global Python for whatever reason, use a virtualenv.

(While we're at it, it's easier to build things with `pip` than to manually find and download the tarballs, expand them, and run the setup.py. But that's a whole other issue.)

Let's say you want to do things this way for some reason. All you need to do is to get numpy onto `sys.path` while you're building `scipy`. For example:

```
$ PYTHONPATH="homepath" python setup.py install --home="homepath"
```

You may want to test this first:

```
$ PYTHONPATH="homepath" python
>>> import numpy
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I did was do python setup.py install --user, which lets me import numpy and scipy without any issues

Comment: @gizgok: OK, glad it helped. Using a user site-directory is much simpler than trying to manage custom directories like you were doing.